# Magento "sorry no quotes are available for this order at this time" 2016 Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Our magento website is currently experiencing this "sorry no quotes are available for this order at this time" issue on the onepage checkout when using the "Pay with Amazon" option. I already tried using the plugin in debug mode and concluded it is probably a Magento issue. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I have been looking around Google search a lot and so far no luck. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue myself in the past. For me it was related to trying to get a quote for shipping rather than the payment process. Check to make sure that you have at least one shipping method enabled in **System > Configuration > Shipping Methods**.

If you are not using a service like FedEx, UPS, etc... to pull rates, then you will need to enable either Free Shipping, Flat Rate Shipping, or Table Rates.

If you are using a service like FedEx, make sure that you select the specific shipping methods for that vendor (i.e. FedEx Ground, Home, etc...)

One other gotcha I have seen, specifically with FedEx Home set as the shipping method, if the package is over 70lbs, they will not return a rate and thus you will get the same error.